# Determine the algebra of derivations of the complex general linear Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I am looking for a hint for the following exercise:

Determine the Lie algebra of derivations $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$ for $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ the complex general linear Lie algebra.

So my first idea was looking at the set of inner derivations, but then I realized that $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not semi-simple, so I don't think that $\operatorname{Inn}(\mathfrak{g}) = \operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$... How would you approach this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)\oplus \Bbb C$, where the first ideal is simple and the second one is abelian.

In general, if we have direct sum of ideals $L=L_1\oplus L_2$, we can express ${\rm Der}(L)$ by ${\rm Der}(L_1)$, ${\rm Der}(L_2)$ and the spaces ${\rm Hom}(L_1,Z(L_2))$, ${\rm Hom}(L_2,Z(L_1))$.

Since $L_1$ is semisimple, ${\rm Der}(L_1)={\rm Inn}(L_1)$ and $Z(L_1)=0$.
Since $L_2$ is abelian, $Z(L_2)=L_2$ and ${\rm Der}(L_2)={\rm End}(L_2)$. For a reference see for example [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/25742558.2019.1624244). 
Note that for $L=\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)$ the center $Z(L)=Z(L_2)$ is $1$-dimensional and is mapped into itself by every derivation.